# Proof the following using laws of equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I got stuck at this question and have been trying to solve it for almost 2 days and I ended up getting confused, any ideas?

Proof the following using laws of equivalence

¬ (a ↔ b)  ≡  (a  ↔ ¬ b)

Answer (score 1):

Which "laws of equivalence" have you been provided with to use? I would at least recommend starting with $p\leftrightarrow q\equiv(p\rightarrow q)\wedge(q\rightarrow p)$ and $p\rightarrow q\equiv\neg p\vee q$. Once you have used these on both sides the best tack is probably to apply one of the distributive laws e.g. $p\wedge(q\vee r)\equiv(p\wedge q)\vee(p\wedge r)$, where a trick you may be missing is that you can put anything you like in the place of $p$, i.e. you could use a more complex term in brackets; you just have to replace every occurrance of $p$ with that term. It would be hepful to see your attempts so far. This would have been posted as a comment but I am not allowed.